# Failed to consume by Python when produced by C# on a Kafka topic with an Avro schema on a schema registry

Tags: python, c#, schema, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We have C# code which is producing records on Kafka and use an Avro schema, we can consume the same topic by C# as well, but when we want to consume it in Python, we get the following error:

`Message deserialization failed: Message deserialization failed for message at [topic name] [4] offset 17: message does not start with magic byte`

and also this procedure is fine when we produce by Python and consume by Python as well.

P.S. IAsyncSerializer is used in C# and AvroConsumer in Python code.

We have tried to serialize records in C# and deserialize the in Python based on the same Avro schema on the schema registry.

Here we have the producer **C# code**:

```
using Avro.IO;
using Avro.Specific;
using Confluent.Kafka;

public class KafkaAvroSerializer<T> : IAsyncSerializer<T>
where T : class, ISpecificRecord
{
    public Task<byte[]> SerializeAsync(T data, SerializationContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
       {
           using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
           {
               var enc = new BinaryEncoder(ms);
               var writer = new SpecificDefaultWriter(data.Schema);
               writer.Write(data, enc);
               return ms.ToArray();
           }
      });
   }
}
```

```
using Avro;
using Avro.Specific;

public class MyRecord : ISpecificRecord
{
   public Schema Schema =>
    Schema.Parse(@”Schema.Parse @"{
      ""name"": ""name "",
      ""namespace"": ""namespace"",
      ""type"": ""record"",
      ""fields"": [
        {
          ""name"": ""field1"",
          ""type"": [
            ""null"",
            ""int""
          ],
          ""default"": null
        },
        {
          ""name"": ""field2"",
          ""type"": [
            ""null"",
            ""string""
          ],
          ""default"": null
        },
        {
          ""name"": ""field3"",
          ""type"": [
            ""null"",
            ""string""
          ],
          ""default"": null
        }
      ]
    }");

public int field1 { get; set; }
public string field2 { get; set; }
public string field3 { get; set; }

public object Get(int fieldPos)
{
    switch (fieldPos)
    {
        case 0: return field1;
        case 1: return field2;
        case 2: return field3;
        default: throw new AvroRuntimeException("Bad index " + fieldPos + " in 
 Get()");
    };
}

public void Put(int fieldPos, object fieldValue)
{
    switch (fieldPos)
    {
        case 0: field1= (int)fieldValue; break;
        case 1: field2= (string)fieldValue; break;
        case 2: field3= (string)fieldValue; break;
        default: throw new AvroRuntimeException("Bad index " + fieldPos + " in 
        Put()");
    };
  }
}
```

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Confluent.SchemaRegistry;
public async Task Publish<T>(T @event) where T 
{
    using (var producer = GetProducer())
    {
        try
        {
            if (@event == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var kafkaEvent = KafkaEventFactory.Create(@event);
            
            var avroModel = AvroModelFactory.Create(kafkaEvent);
            var message = new Message<string, MyRecord>() { Value = avroModel, Key = kafkaEvent.Key };

            var deliveryResult = await producer.ProduceAsync(_kafkaOption.Topic, message);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Delivered '{deliveryResult.Value}' to '{deliveryResult.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
        }
        catch (ProduceException<string, MyRecord> e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
private IProducer<string, MyRecord> GetProducer()
{
    var config = GetProducerConfig();
    var schemaRegistry = GetSchemaRegistry();

    var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, MyRecord >(config)
        .SetErrorHandler((_, error) =>
        {
            _logger.LogError(error.ToString());
        })
        .SetValueSerializer(new KafkaAvroSerializer< MyRecord >())
        .Build();

    return producer;
}

private ProducerConfig GetProducerConfig()
{
    return new ProducerConfig
    {
        BootstrapServers = “BootstrapServers”
    };
}

private CachedSchemaRegistryClient GetSchemaRegistry()
{
    return new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new SchemaRegistryConfig { Url = 
 “SchemaRegistryUrl” });
 }
```

And also this is the consumer code by **Python**:

```
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroConsumer
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import SerializerError
from confluent_kafka import avro
import requests

bootstrap_servers = '[bootstrap_server_ip]:[bootstrap_server_port]'
topic = '[topic_name]'

schema_registry_url = "http://[schema_registry_ip]:[schema_registry_port]"
avro_schema_name = "[schema_name]"

consumer_config = {
   'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers,
   'schema.registry.url': schema_registry_url,
   'group.id': '8',
   "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
}

def fetch_avro_schema(schema_registry_url, schema_name):
    url = f"{schema_registry_url}/subjects/{schema_name}/versions/latest"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        schema = response.json()["schema"]
        return avro.loads(schema)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Failed to fetch Avro schema for {schema_name}.")
try:
    avro_schema = fetch_avro_schema(schema_registry_url, avro_schema_name)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"While fetch avro schema {e}")

try:
    consumer = AvroConsumer(consumer_config, reader_value_schema=avro_schema)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"While Avro Consumer {e}")

try:
    consumer.subscribe([topic])
except Exception as e:
    print(f"While Subscribing Topic {e}")

while True:
    try:
        message = consumer.poll(1)
        if message is None:
            continue

        # Deserialize with schema
        print(message.value())
        break
    except SerializerError as e:
        print(f"Message deserialization failed: {e}")
```

I expect that when we produce and consume with the same schema, we can do the procedure without any errors! but I get this error when I wanna consume it by Python:

`Message deserialization failed: Message deserialization failed for message at [topic name] [4] offset 17: message does not start with magic byte`